Hello, I have solana dedicated rpc url and I want to call this rpc and fetch on chain price of token. so please guide me how can I do this?
I have solana dedicated rpc url and I want to call this rpc and fetch on chain price of token. so please guide me how can I do this?

not sure how to use rpc to get on chain price of a token but you can use the birdeye API for the same thing
You would first need to set up a birdeye account here https://bds.birdeye.so/auth/sign-up to obtain an API key
Once you obtain an API key this snippet would help u obtain on chain price of an Token
you'll need to head to install Axios for this run npm
install axios --save
import axios from 'axios';

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://public-api.birdeye.so/defi/price',
  params: {address: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112'},
  headers: {'X-API-KEY': 'fee268b6fd074192b7280d8e7a2a74ed'}
};

axios
  .request(options)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });

full process/birdeye token price documentation here
https://docs.birdeye.so/reference/get_defi-price

I understand that to get the token price, you need to use a DEX, not an RPC URL.
here is a example use Jupiter API:
const url = `https://price.jup.ag/v6/price?ids=${symbol}`;
try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const data = response.data;
    console.log(data)
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching symbol price:', error);
}    

